# Got runtime error when coding in my apache tomcat

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to show my data from my MongoDB to my html. The data was in the MongoDB, but it won't show on my html. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#buttonlogin" ).click(function(){
                masuklogin();
            });
        });


        function masuklogin(){
            var formdata = {
                    nomortelp : $("#nomortelp").val(),
                    password : $("#password").val()
            };

            var Jformdata = JSON.stringify(formdata);

            console.log(Jformdata);


            $.ajax({
                url : "/Dompetku/BankMasuk",
                context : document.body,
            }).done(function (response){

                console.log(response);
                console.log("ini kerja");
                var table = "";
                table += "<table class = 'table'> ";
                table += "<thread>";
                table += "<tr>";
                table += "<th>" + "Username" +"</th>";
                table += "<th>" + "Password" +"</th>";
                table += "<tr>";
                table += "<thread>";

                response.forEach(function(BankSinarmas) {

                    table += "<tr>";
                    table += "<th>" + BankSinarmas.nomortelp; +"</th>";
                    table += "<th>" + BankSinarmas.password; +"</th>";
                    table += "<tr>";
                });

                table += "</table>";
                $(".initable").html(table);

        });

    }
```

And my error goes through like this:

```
index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: masuk is not defined(anonymous function) @ index.js:3dispatch @ jquery-3.0.0.min.js:5q.handle @ jquery-3.0.0.min.js:5
```

Doesn't it suppose to read `masuklogin()`   function instead of `masuk()` function?
Thanks before and I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: you know that this code is javascript and not java? since you tagged the question as a java question :)